If the analytic rank is one then the sign in the functional equation is -1?
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbf{Q}$. Let $L(E, s)$ denote its $L$-function over $\mathbf{Q}$. Also $f$ denotes the weight two cusp form associated to $E$, but this shouldn't be important.
In section V.2 of their paper Heegner points and derivatives of $L$-series Gross and Zagier say

assume $\textrm{ord}_{s = 1} L(E, s) = 1$. In particular, the sign in the functional equation of $L(E, s) = L(f, s)$ is $-1$

Does anybody know a reference for this fact?
Apologies if it's something obvious that I have overlooked.

This is something you can definitely use without a reference. The functional equation is $L(f,s)=\epsilon L(f,2-s)$ for some sign $\epsilon$.
Let $F(z)=L(f,1+z)$, then $F(z)=\epsilon F(-z)$.
So if $\epsilon=1$, then $F$ is a power series in $z^2$ and the vanishing order of $F$ at $0$ (hence of $L(f,s)$ at $s=1$) is even.
On the ither hand, if $\epsilon=-1$, then the Taylor expansion of $F(z)$ at $0$ is of the form $\sum_{n\geq 0}{a_nz^{2n+1}}$, so the vanishing order of $F$ at $0$ (hence of $L(f,s)$ at $s=1$) is odd.

Aha I did overlook something simple! Brilliant! Many thanks
